# Chrome extension - disable autocomplete of fields

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

We have figured out a bug in our extension that is related to Chrome autofilling fields (eg: username/passwords) and interfering with things.

Alternatively, if we could figure out what fields Chrome has automatically populated we can probably work around it.

Is it possible for a Chrome extension to disable this feature of Chrome?

Thanks

Comment: You could add the `autocomplete="off"` attribute to the `form`s and `input`s

Comment: Chrome ignores the autocomplete attribute in Chrome 34+ it seems.